# Select users who have not signed up for an interview

Tags: mysql, select, join

I have two tables, `interviews` and `users`.

*inteviews* looks like this:

[image: Interviews Table]

*users* looks like this:

[image]

The `id` column in the user table will match the `user` column in the interviews table.  How can I select all users that **have not** signed up for an interview?

(E.g. something along the lines of "select * from interviews left join users on interviews.id <> users.id")

Comment: That `time` column... wouldn't be a foreign key to a table full of actual time values, would it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'd want all the users that does not have an entry in the interviews table:

```
 SELECT users.* FROM users LEFT JOIN interviews 
   ON users.id = interviews.id WHERE interviews.id IS NULL
```

(from the looks of the tables, it sounds like it's users.id that should be joined on interviews.user though)

Comment: Probably. the Op states that users.id matches inerviews.id though

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT u.*
FROM Users u
LEFT JOIN Interviews i ON u.id = i.user
WHERE i.id IS NULL
```